# Azure SQL Database vs. error 8152 enhancement

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, trace-flags

How can I take advantage of the enhancement for error 8152 (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-replacing-the-infamous-error-8152/) in Azure SQL Database? Even when logged in as the Server admin, I can't set the trace flag.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot enable traceflags in azure sql database (single database).

You can enable traceflags when using azure sql database managed instances:

[image]

[DBCC TRACEON documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

---

Since the azure sql database service is based on the latest stable sql server version

> It's (azure sql database) based on the latest stable version of the
>   Microsoft SQL Server database engine.

[Azure sql database service documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-technical-overview)

And  in your [linked source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-replacing-the-infamous-error-8152/) it is stated that:

> ...Note that for now, even in SQL Server 2019 CTP 2.0 the same trace
>   flag 460 needs to be enabled. In a future SQL Server 2019 release,
>   message 2628 will replace message 8152 by default....

We should hope to see this more detailed error message enabled by default for the azure sql database service in the future, once that build is deemed stable.

Comment: It's now March 2021 and it still doesn't seem like it's possible to use Trace 460 with Azure SQL :/